# Setting up password less login on remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, ssh-keys

I am trying to set up password less login to my remote server that I use for work. Currently I have to type in my password every time to login, and then again to switch to the `appuser` using `sudo su - appuser`. I am trying to first add my local public key to the server. I have generated a key pair on my local machine and used ssh-copy-id to copy my public key to the `/export/home/myusername/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. I have also double checked permissions: `chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys`. Why am I still prompted for a password after everything is done?

Here is the log using `-vv`

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
    debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for server1
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to server1 port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    .....
    debug1: Host 'server1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/users/.ssh/known_hosts:7
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:...
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

 Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:...
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: According to the debug output, your ssh client offered `id_rsa` to the server and the server didn't accept it. You could try checking the ssh server log on the remote system to see if it logged a reason. On a typical unix system, sshd might log through syslog to files in `/var/log`.

Comment: @kenster going into `/var/log` I do not see a `auth.log` in there anywhere -- or anything that looks like it might be related

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually copy the /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key to the remote server ->  /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys .

You can also try:

ssh user@remoteserver -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (without .pub).